# Parallel translation via $e$-connection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, information-theory, information-geometry

This question is concerned with Section 2.5. of Amari and Nagaoka's Information geometry
book. Let me give some background first. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the
$n$-dimensional manifold of all (strictly positive) probability distributions on
$\mathcal{X}=\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}$. Each $p=(p(x_0),\dots,p(x_n))\in \mathcal{P}$ is thought of a point in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathcal{X}}:=\{A \big|~A:\mathcal{X}\to \mathbb{R}\}$. Hence the tangent space $T_p(\mathcal{P})$ at each point $p$ is $\{A\big|\sum_x A(x)=0\}$. For two tangent vectors $X,Y\in T_p(\mathcal{P})$, a Riemannian metric (the Fisher information metric) is given by 
$$\langle X,Y\rangle^{(e)}_p:=E_p[X^{(e)}Y^{(e)}],$$
where $X^{(e)}(x)=X(x)/p(x)$ is called the exponential representation of $X$ at $p$. One can show that $\{X^{(e)}\big| X\in T_p(\mathcal{P})\}=\{A\big|E_p[A]=0\}$.

Now, let $[\xi^i]$ be a coordinate system on $\mathcal{P}$ with $\{\partial_i:=\partial/\partial_{\xi_i}\}$ being the natural basis and $(\partial_i^{(e)})_{p_{\xi}}:=\partial_i\log p_{\xi}$. The exponential connection ($e$-connection) on $\mathcal{P}$ with respect to this coordinate system is given by 
\begin{eqnarray}
\Gamma_{ij,k} &:=& \langle \nabla_{\partial_i}^{(e)}\partial_j,\partial_k\rangle\\
&=& \sum_x\partial_i(\partial_j\log p_{\xi}(x))\cdot \partial_k p_{\xi}(x)\\
&=& E_{p_{\xi}}[\partial_i(\partial_j\log p_{\xi})~\partial_k \log p_{\xi}].
\end{eqnarray}

They claim the following regarding the $e$-connection:

\begin{eqnarray}
\label{eq1}
\tag{1}
\Pi_{p,q}^{(e)}(X)=X'\Longleftrightarrow X_q'^{(e)}=X_p^{(e)}-E_q[X_p^{(e)}],
\end{eqnarray}

i.e., the tangent vector $X$ at $p$ is parallelly translated to $X'$ at
$q$ iff $X_q'^{(e)}=X_p^{(e)}-E_q[X_p^{(e)}]$.

The 'if' part seems clear. Indeed, if $X:p\mapsto X_p$ is an arbitrary vector field on
$\mathcal{P}$ such that $X_q^{(e)}=X_p^{(e)}-E_q[X_p^{(e)}]$, then $X_q^{(e)}=F-E_q[F]$ for all $q\in \mathcal{P}$, where $F$ is some real valued function on $\mathcal{X}$. hence $\partial_i(X_p^{(e)}(x)) = -\partial_i(\mathbb{E}_p[F])$, a constant as a function of $x$, for any $p$, and hence 
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle \nabla_{\partial_i}^{(e)}X, \partial_k\rangle_p &=&\mathbb{E}_p[ \partial_i(X_p^{(e)})(\partial_k)_p^{(e)}]\\
 & = & -\partial_i(\mathbb{E}_p[F])\cdot \mathbb{E}_p[(\partial_k)_p^{(e)}]\\
 & = & 0,
\end{eqnarray}
hence $X$ is $e$-parallel.

Although they seems to have concluded the entire claim by the above argument, I'm not convinced. My question is, does the 'only if' part of (\ref{eq1}) also follow from this? Or is it easy to see from someother argument? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I try to give an answer myself. I'm not sure whether it is correct. If someone can verify this, it would be helpful.

Suppose that $X$ is a parallel vector field w.r.to the $e$-connection. Then $\langle \nabla_{\partial_i}^{(e)}X, \partial_k\rangle_{p_{\xi}}=0$ for all $p_{\xi}$. Then $\partial_i(X_{p_{\xi}}^{(e)}(x))=f(\xi)$, a constant w.r.to $x$. This is true for all $i$. This implies that $X_{p_{\xi}}^{(e)}(x)=g(\xi)+h(x)$. Since $E[X_{p_{\xi}}^{(e)}]=0$, we have $E_{p_{\xi}}[h]=-g(\xi)$ and hence $X_{p_{\xi}}^{(e)}(x)=h(x)-E_{p_{\xi}}[h]$.